# Moderators on Channels are missing ♦ behind their names

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderators, stack-overflow-for-teams

We have a moderator on our Channel ([proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gICl.png)), but there's no ♦ to be found:

[image]

Comment: I think they need to accept the mod agreement. Have they?

Comment: And note that you'll need to manually key in the URL. It was the same issue in SO Enterprise. (If that does not work, then it's not implemented)

Comment: That's assuming it's going to show a diamond like the public site?

Comment: @JonClements The community user has a diamond

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Yes, I have accepted the agreement. I edited it manually and made it work, but the process is still bugged.

Comment: @ArtOfCode Oh, sorry, I guess there are lots of things in need of fixing with channels

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth it's not as bad as Documentation was.

Comment: @Glorfindel Says the person that just flooded meta with 5 bug reports in under 2 hours ;)

Comment: Yeah, I expected to get rate-limited but I didn't. With Documentation we had pages full of bugs/discussions: http://i.stack.imgur.com/kNcgw.png

Comment: I'd say it's bug. The Community user has one. Bhargav's diamond doesn't show up in most places, although he is admin in the channel

Comment: Unfortunately, by design. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364333/most-of-the-moderation-links-on-channels-link-to-those-on-stack-overflow-instead

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to have been solved, moderators on Stack Overflow for Teams are now recognizable but they get a *hexagon* instead of a diamond:

[image]

Comment: Wait, you recognized that today? It was done in the April 12 mass deploy.

Comment: I recognized it earlier, but I didn't remember that my question was still open :)

Comment: Nice, a low-poly circle!

Comment: Mods should get a freehand red circle around their names. Don't settle for a hexagon!