# Most of the moderation links on Channels link to those on Stack Overflow instead

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams

Contacting CMs and perhaps sending suspensions on channels makes me contact the user with the same user ID on Stack Overflow.

I would have tested out suspending myself, but it might lead to suspending Joel Spolsky, as I am user/4 on the channel.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At launch we don't plan on having diamond moderators. We're removing links to many of the moderator tools and we're going to be removing the routes too. None of them should have an effect on the main site, but some links from a channel might go to a page on the main site so be careful. Look at the URL to be sure.

As for the need (or lack thereof) for moderators, here's what I asked on our internal channel:

---

## Can we do without diamond moderators on Teams?

According to our [theory of moderation](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/):

> What do community moderators do? The short answer is, **as little as possible!**

Looking at items we can/should remove from the mod menus, it seems like there's not much left for diamond moderators to do on a Team. Most of the actions on a post can be done by regular users (especially given our reduced privilege levels) or are unnecessary on a private site (such as protecting a question). Moderator actions on a user profile are probably the domain of the admin (especially removing users) or HR (annotate, suspend, mod message, etc.) The remaining items, by my reckoning, are:

1. Binding close and delete votes. (Could be given to other users by knocking the site setting to one vote required.)
2. Managing tag synonyms. (There is a process for community-created synonyms, but, [yeah, that's not going to work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127459/does-the-tag-synonym-suggestion-system-work) on a private site.)
3. Merging questions. (But this is an often misunderstood and destructive tool. Probably best to ask the person who answered one of the questions to copy their answer over.)
4. Redaction. (Might be an admin function and needs streamlining for private channels.)
5. Comments. (I have parentheticals on the other items, so I feel I need one here too. How about reading [my proposal for giving comment moderation to high-reputation users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252691/1438)?)

Presumably the admin would appoint moderators, but how would they be different than other users? Can we avoid having content moderators and just rely on individuals to police themselves?

Comment: Oops okay. I'll create a different sock account to test the mod stuff. I don't want to get demodded here because I did some crazy stuff. :p

Comment: @BhargavRao: On the whole, that sounds like a solid plan. But be aware that testing mod routes is probably a waste of time since we're still in the process of cauterizing them.

Comment: Yup, I will surely stop testing now after some weird things started ... :(

Answer (score 10):

As Jon said, there are no plans for Teams having moderators at the moment. We're waiting to gather some feedback on which tools would actually be useful and necessary instead of just replicating all of what public SO has as is. If nothing else, most of our tools are unintuitive on the best of days.

I'm tagging this as [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) because revisiting moderation *is* on our list, but we don't necessarily have an ETA in the short term.

**In the meantime**, please refrain from poking holes in the tools that are known broken, especially if you already have mod access on public SO. It *shouldn't* affect anything on the public site, but I'm really not 100% positive on that. Not to mention any number of unexpected things that could happen *within* a Team. Thanks, and I'll be sure to give you a shout when we're ready with some mod tools. :)

Answer (score 2):

This has been fixed! And by fixed, we removed the links from Teams. We still don't have any plans to have moderators on Teams, so we decided to remove the links until we revisit that feature.