# Remove the quality filters from Stack Overflow for Teams, or allow Team Admins to remove post-bans

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams, post-ban

One of my accounts in SO teams is blocked from answering with the reason `We are no longer accepting answers from this account`. Can this be removed? Or allow team admins to lift it.

This is not a dupe of [Should we get rid of the quality-control bans in channels?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364378) as it also asks for allowing team admins to lift it and not be limited to a policy. Also not a dupe of [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) as this question is asking if this feature can be removed.

Comment: Q-Bans exists on Teams? Wow. And you managed to get caught by a q-ban on Teams? Double wow.

Comment: @yivi I am not sure if Q-bans exists in SO teams, but my account was caught by a quality warning. My test account got A-banned. I needed to destroy the account in order to remove the answer ban.

Comment: @yivi I am the team admin. And there is no way to lift it.

Comment: It's a weird team you are managing there. Being Team Admin and getting a quality warning it's a rather unexpected corner case, I hope.

Comment: I think it is a dupe of the first question, which contains "Can we get rid of the quality control bans on private channels and/or restrict them to the company policies?"

Comment: PM on Teams here. This seems funky -- we're looking into it.