# What are the rules for reputation and privileges for Teams?

Tags: support, status-deferred, reputation, stack-overflow-for-teams, privileges

I've looked at Teams recently, and I was slightly confused - do the normal rules for reputation and privileges apply on Teams?

Comment: No, they are not the same. There is a completely separate privileges page on Teams. Feel free to check it out.

Comment: Sorry @BhargavRao, I can't find it - can you please provide a link? (the question was confusing - I don't *have* Teams, I want to see the privileges for teams)

Comment: There's really nothing much to see. Almost every privilege is available to 1-rep Team members. The help article about reputation on Teams is wrong and needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All the general privileges on Teams are set to 1. These include:

- create/edit posts
- comment everywhere
- create/edit community wiki
- create tags
- see vote counts
- cast/view close/reopen votes

The "start bounties" privilege is set at reputation 75, as you need enough reputation to start bounties. Some privileges that are totally missing from Teams are:

- protect questions
- view deleted posts (available for admins)
- view analytics
- create tag synonyms (available for admins)
- flag posts

and of course "reduce ads"!

Comment: And even admins can't see deleted comments. :/

Comment: You can see them in the timeline, @Cat. Not on the post itself.

Comment: Yeah, well most people can't get to the timeline because there's no links... but thanks for the hint.

Comment: Is there such a thing as a moderator on Teams? Or is it only admins and team members? And is "admin" status available to be "granted", e.g. if I'm an admin, can I let someone else become an admin?

Comment: @JackBashford no, yes, yes. But you need to be cautious about admin access because it includes billing stuff.

Comment: @JackBashford Admin is like a moderator on the team (they have a hexagon instead of a diamond). You can add anyone else as an admin, if you're an admin.

Comment: So it's essentially the rules of SO, but `moderator = admin`?

Comment: @JackBashford, Not quite, the role of an admin is more related to administration of the team rather than moderation. There are very little aspects of moderation that admins need to do.

Comment: @JackBashford Hardly. Since it's your Team, you can decide what is on and off topic. If you want to ask what people want to order for lunch or poll people about their favorite computer build, that's your choice. There's only two close reasons, duplicate and off topic, which require only one vote to close. There's no review queues.

Comment: Jon Ericson goes into some [detail on why we don't have heavy moderation related infrastructure in teams](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/364336/4099593).

Comment: One last thing - is there a "redact" on Teams like on SO? e.g. if an API key was published, would it be possible to remove it from the revision history?

Comment: @JackBashford, yep, there is. Any admin can redact single handedly.

Answer (score 1):

Bhargav Rao is correct and you're absolutely correct that this can be confusing. We are thinking about it; we know it is a problem and we are thinking of ways to solve this, but it's not going to be resolved in the near term.