# Why do I need 125 rep to downvote on Teams?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow-for-teams

Is there a reason why on Teams sites the "Downvote" privilege requires 125 reputation?

The is a is useful mechanism for more discussion based teams (i.e. moderators) - and requiring 125 rep seems to remove the ability to participate for a number of users:

[image: 125 rep required to downvote]

Couple this with the fact that downvoting isn't even shown on the Teams privileges page at all (no privileges above 75 rep are shown on those pages) it seems like there was an oversight there.

I appreciate that setting bounties [requires 75 rep](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/388227/33051) so that you have some rep to give, but as downvotes only cost 2 rep, shouldn't this be allowed sooner?

Note, apparently "a CM has already asked questions about it (not a meta post though). They're aware of it, and they're on it.", but raising here for visibility and tracking.

Comment: Cross posted under advice [from MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/335846/33051).

Answer (score -5):

This is by design although I'm not sure why we landed on 125 reputation. I've added that limitation to this help article, https://www.stackoverflow.help/support/solutions/articles/36000042869-reputation.

Comment: [The public Q&As require 125 reputation for downvoting.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) If I understand Zhaph correctly, it's not different; it's the same. If they're supposed to be different, that might be a bug.

Comment: @jpmc26 you're right, I'm more interested in why I need 125 rep to downvote on teams, than why it's not listed on the page, so I've updated the question to focus more on that. Thanks :)

Comment: 125 rep to downvote isn't listed on the privileges page. It's slightly misleading when all the other privileges (aside bounties) are unlocked at one rep

Comment: That makes total sense. I’ll double check on Monday, if it’s the same as SO, most likely we simply used the default value from Public Q&A when we built Teams. I’ll make sure to update the help document.