# Who can close questions in Stack Overflow for Teams?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-for-teams, privileges

On Stack Overflow for Teams, who can vote to close questions, and has this changed in the past few months?

https://stackoverflow.help/en/collections/2531034-getting-started doesn't have any information on closing privileges, and https://stackoverflow.help/en/articles/4396982-reputation doesn't indicate a reputation amount for closing in particular - it only talks about moderator privileges at 75 rep.

Edit: To close a question nowadays, you have to click on "Manage" and then "Close", or possibly "Mark obsolete".

Comment: Duplicate of [What are the rules for reputation and privileges for Teams?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388227/what-are-the-rules-for-reputation-and-privileges-for-teams) --> _"All the general privileges on Teams are set to 1. These include: [...] - cast/view close/reopen votes"_