# Suggesting tag synonyms on Channels requires int.MaxValue reputation

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams, tag-synonym-process, privileges

The 'Suggesting tag synonyms' privilege hasn't been assigned to a reputation, so it'll take even Jon Skeet a long time to get the necessary reputation. My iPhone even thinks it's a phone number and not a reputation level...

[Link to specific tag synonym page](https://stackoverflow.com/c/charcoal/tags/10/synonyms)

[image]

Comment: Better get answerin'.

Comment: Doesn't help. I've already reached the rep cap today ...

Comment: Jon Skeet will apply soon so I don't see the problem here.

Comment: Are you still sure it's not as bad as Documentation?

Comment: I am more concerned about the links next to "Tag Info" header. It reads like "users new hot synonyms" - so... *new hot synonyms of the user* ...right?

Comment: What has a bug todo with a whole concept? @jpmc26

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt jpmc26 is probably replying to [this comment of mine](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364323/moderators-on-channels-are-missing-behind-their-names#comment563579_364323).

Comment: And it's definitely not as bad as Documentation; for some context about that, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/329143/4751173

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt I was making a joke because I've been seeing a bunch of Glorfindel's bug reports about [tag:channels] show up in the side bar over the past few days, and I happened to recall the comment he linked. ;)

Comment: I assume this is not an issue any more, @Glorfindel, but thought I'd check?

Comment: @JNat in both teams I'm a member of, I don't see that message anymore, but I am not able to tell if that's because the bug is fixed or that I have enough reputation for the current level :)

Comment: Marking as [status-completed] because I can't repro this any more. If someone can still repro it, please let me know.